# How to detect if a research team is outsourcing writing to increase paper publishing?

Tags: technical-writing, academic-writing, research, scientific-publishing, paper

I have suspicions of a situation where a Computational Science research group is using paid writing services (outsourcing, using AI or human services) to increase their publication ratio in scientific journals.

Beyond the ethical issues, do you have any ideas or experiences to confirm these suspicions?

For example some tool to compare the ratio of publications between competitive teams (meaning, publishing in the same scientific area).

On the other hand, probably this is a common practice these days?

Comment: You can, to some extent, do author identification based on properties of a text (e.g. https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8894872 ) So you could use that to try to determine which (if any) team members wrote the publications. But I'd worry about whether the accuracy is good enough to avoid false positives/false negatives.

Comment: By ratio do you mean papers published:rejected?  How would you obtain the rejected figure?  Publishers are unlikely to make it public.

Comment: I'd ask this question on Academic Stack Exchange instead.